# What happens with unmatched dispatch_group_enter and dispatch_group_leave?

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

I have an async `NSOperation` to download data for multiple `ImageFile` objects. Since this is all happening asynchronously I am using a dispatch group to track the requests and then `dispatch_group_notify` to complete the operation when they are all done.

The question I have is what happen when the operation is ended prematurely, either by cancelation or by some other error. The dispatch group will be left with unmatched `dispatch_group_enter` and `dispatch_group_leave` so `dispatch_group_notify` will never be called. Is it the block retained somewhere by the system forever waiting, or will it get released when the `NSOperation` gets released?

Or is my approach not ideal, how else should I do this?

```
- (void)main
{
    if (self.cancelled) {
        [self completeOperation];
        return;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;

    [context performBlock:^{

        NSFetchRequest *request = [ImageFile fetchRequest];
        request.predicate = ....
        request.sortDescriptors = ...

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *imageFiles = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if (!imageFiles) {
            // Error handling...
            [self completeOperation];
            return;
        }

        dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

        for (ImageFile *imageFile in imageFiles) {
            dispatch_group_enter(group);
            @autoreleasepool {
                [self.webService requestImageWithId:imageFile.id completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                    if (self.cancelled) {
                        [self completeOperation];
                        return;
                    }

                    [context performBlock:^{
                        if (data && !error) {
                            imageFile.data = data;
                            NSError *error;
                            if (![context save:&error]) {
                                // Error handling...
                                [self completeOperation];
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        dispatch_group_leave(group);
                    }];
                }];
            }
        }

        dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self completeOperation];
        });
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs for `dispatch_group_enter()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1452803-dispatch_group_enter):

> A call to this function must be balanced with a call to `dispatch_group_leave`.

From the [docs for `dispatch_group_t`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatch_group_t):

> The dispatch group keeps track of how many blocks are outstanding, and GCD retains the group until all its associated blocks complete execution.

It talks about outstanding blocks, but what it really means is unmatched calls to `dispatch_group_enter()`.

So, the answer to your question about what happens is that the dispatch group object effectively leaks. The block object passed to `dispatch_group_notify()` and any objects it has strong references to also leak. In your case, that includes `self`.

The answer to your question of whether your approach is "ideal" is: no, it's not ideal. It's not even valid by the design contract of GCD. You **must** balance all calls to `dispatch_group_enter()` with calls to `dispatch_group_leave()`.

If you want to somehow distinguish between success and failure or normal completion and cancellation, you should set some state that's available to the notify block and then code the notify block to consult that state to decide what to do.

In your case, though, the code paths where you fail to call `dispatch_group_leave()` just do the same thing the notify block would do. So I'm not even sure why you're not just calling `dispatch_group_leave()` rather than calling `[self completeOperation]` in those cases.